# No puedo instalar node opus

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

no me instala node opus me sale el un error,ya he probado a reinstalar todos los paquetes relacionados con este y no funciona alguna sugerencia? el error es el siguiente: https://hastebin.com/rupahucipe.tex

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'node-opus',
1 verbose cli   '-g' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.6.0
4 verbose npm-session 971d43320a2bdc8d
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-opus 14ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for node-opus@latest fetched in 44ms
9 silly install loadIdealTree
10 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
11 silly install loadShrinkwrap
12 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
13 silly resolveWithNewModule node-opus@0.2.7 checking installable status
14 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan 36ms (from cache)
15 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ogg-packet 37ms (from cache)
16 silly pacote range manifest for nan@^2.3.2 fetched in 38ms
17 silly resolveWithNewModule nan@2.7.0 checking installable status
18 silly pacote range manifest for ogg-packet@^1.0.0 fetched in 39ms
19 silly resolveWithNewModule ogg-packet@1.0.0 checking installable status
20 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander 123ms (from cache)
21 silly pacote range manifest for commander@^2.9.0 fetched in 124ms
22 silly resolveWithNewModule commander@2.11.0 checking installable status
23 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings 293ms (from cache)
24 silly pacote range manifest for bindings@~1.2.1 fetched in 296ms
25 silly resolveWithNewModule bindings@1.2.1 checking installable status
26 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ref-struct 2ms (from cache)
27 silly pacote range manifest for ref-struct@* fetched in 2ms
28 silly resolveWithNewModule ref-struct@1.1.0 checking installable status
29 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ref 4ms (from cache)
30 silly pacote range manifest for ref@1 fetched in 5ms
31 silly resolveWithNewModule ref@1.3.5 checking installable status
32 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug 25ms (from cache)
33 silly pacote range manifest for debug@2 fetched in 29ms
34 silly resolveWithNewModule debug@2.6.9 checking installable status
35 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms 3ms (from cache)
36 silly pacote version manifest for ms@2.0.0 fetched in 5ms
37 silly resolveWithNewModule ms@2.0.0 checking installable status
38 silly currentTree npm
39 silly idealTree npm
39 silly idealTree `-- node-opus@0.2.7
39 silly idealTree   +-- bindings@1.2.1
39 silly idealTree   +-- commander@2.11.0
39 silly idealTree   +-- debug@2.6.9
39 silly idealTree   +-- ms@2.0.0
39 silly idealTree   +-- nan@2.7.0
39 silly idealTree   +-- ogg-packet@1.0.0
39 silly idealTree   +-- ref-struct@1.1.0
39 silly idealTree   `-- ref@1.3.5
40 silly install generateActionsToTake
41 silly diffTrees action count 9
42 silly diffTrees add bindings@1.2.1
43 silly diffTrees add ms@2.0.0
44 silly diffTrees add debug@2.6.9
45 silly diffTrees add nan@2.7.0
46 silly diffTrees add ref@1.3.5
47 silly diffTrees add ref-struct@1.1.0
48 silly diffTrees add commander@2.11.0
49 silly diffTrees add ogg-packet@1.0.0
50 silly diffTrees add node-opus@0.2.7
51 silly decomposeActions action count 72
52 silly decomposeActions fetch bindings@1.2.1
53 silly decomposeActions extract bindings@1.2.1
54 silly decomposeActions preinstall bindings@1.2.1
55 silly decomposeActions build bindings@1.2.1
56 silly decomposeActions install bindings@1.2.1
57 silly decomposeActions postinstall bindings@1.2.1
58 silly decomposeActions finalize bindings@1.2.1
59 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json bindings@1.2.1
60 silly decomposeActions fetch ms@2.0.0
61 silly decomposeActions extract ms@2.0.0
62 silly decomposeActions preinstall ms@2.0.0
63 silly decomposeActions build ms@2.0.0
64 silly decomposeActions install ms@2.0.0
65 silly decomposeActions postinstall ms@2.0.0
66 silly decomposeActions finalize ms@2.0.0
67 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json ms@2.0.0
68 silly decomposeActions fetch debug@2.6.9
69 silly decomposeActions extract debug@2.6.9
70 silly decomposeActions preinstall debug@2.6.9
71 silly decomposeActions build debug@2.6.9
72 silly decomposeActions install debug@2.6.9
73 silly decomposeActions postinstall debug@2.6.9
74 silly decomposeActions finalize debug@2.6.9
75 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json debug@2.6.9
76 silly decomposeActions fetch nan@2.7.0
77 silly decomposeActions extract nan@2.7.0
78 silly decomposeActions preinstall nan@2.7.0
79 silly decomposeActions build nan@2.7.0
80 silly decomposeActions install nan@2.7.0
81 silly decomposeActions postinstall nan@2.7.0
82 silly decomposeActions finalize nan@2.7.0
83 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json nan@2.7.0
84 silly decomposeActions fetch ref@1.3.5
85 silly decomposeActions extract ref@1.3.5
86 silly decomposeActions preinstall ref@1.3.5
87 silly decomposeActions build ref@1.3.5
88 silly decomposeActions install ref@1.3.5
89 silly decomposeActions postinstall ref@1.3.5
90 silly decomposeActions finalize ref@1.3.5
91 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json ref@1.3.5
92 silly decomposeActions fetch ref-struct@1.1.0
93 silly decomposeActions extract ref-struct@1.1.0
94 silly decomposeActions preinstall ref-struct@1.1.0
95 silly decomposeActions build ref-struct@1.1.0
96 silly decomposeActions install ref-struct@1.1.0
97 silly decomposeActions postinstall ref-struct@1.1.0
98 silly decomposeActions finalize ref-struct@1.1.0
99 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json ref-struct@1.1.0
100 silly decomposeActions fetch commander@2.11.0
101 silly decomposeActions extract commander@2.11.0
102 silly decomposeActions preinstall commander@2.11.0
103 silly decomposeActions build commander@2.11.0
104 silly decomposeActions install commander@2.11.0
105 silly decomposeActions postinstall commander@2.11.0
106 silly decomposeActions finalize commander@2.11.0
107 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json commander@2.11.0
108 silly decomposeActions fetch ogg-packet@1.0.0
109 silly decomposeActions extract ogg-packet@1.0.0
110 silly decomposeActions preinstall ogg-packet@1.0.0
111 silly decomposeActions build ogg-packet@1.0.0
112 silly decomposeActions install ogg-packet@1.0.0
113 silly decomposeActions postinstall ogg-packet@1.0.0
114 silly decomposeActions finalize ogg-packet@1.0.0
115 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json ogg-packet@1.0.0
116 silly decomposeActions fetch node-opus@0.2.7
117 silly decomposeActions extract node-opus@0.2.7
118 silly decomposeActions preinstall node-opus@0.2.7
119 silly decomposeActions build node-opus@0.2.7
120 silly decomposeActions install node-opus@0.2.7
121 silly decomposeActions postinstall node-opus@0.2.7
122 silly decomposeActions finalize node-opus@0.2.7
123 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json node-opus@0.2.7
124 silly install executeActions
125 silly doSerial global-install 72
126 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
127 verbose lock using C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-5371d44cf1cca0da.lock for C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging
128 silly doParallel extract 72
129 silly extract bindings@1.2.1
130 silly extract ms@2.0.0
131 silly extract debug@2.6.9
132 silly extract nan@2.7.0
133 silly extract ref@1.3.5
134 silly extract ref-struct@1.1.0
135 silly extract commander@2.11.0
136 silly extract ogg-packet@1.0.0
137 silly extract node-opus@0.2.7
138 silly doReverseSerial unbuild 72
139 silly doSerial remove 72
140 silly doSerial move 72
141 silly doSerial finalize 72
142 silly finalize C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\bindings
143 silly finalize C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ms
144 silly finalize C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\debug
145 silly finalize C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\nan
146 silly finalize C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ref
147 silly finalize C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ref-struct
148 silly finalize C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\commander
149 silly finalize C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ogg-packet
150 silly finalize C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus
151 silly doParallel refresh-package-json 72
152 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\bindings
153 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ms
154 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\debug
155 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\nan
156 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ref
157 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ref-struct
158 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\commander
159 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ogg-packet
160 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus
161 silly doParallel preinstall 72
162 silly preinstall bindings@1.2.1
163 info lifecycle bindings@1.2.1~preinstall: bindings@1.2.1
164 silly preinstall ms@2.0.0
165 info lifecycle ms@2.0.0~preinstall: ms@2.0.0
166 silly preinstall debug@2.6.9
167 info lifecycle debug@2.6.9~preinstall: debug@2.6.9
168 silly preinstall nan@2.7.0
169 info lifecycle nan@2.7.0~preinstall: nan@2.7.0
170 silly preinstall ref@1.3.5
171 info lifecycle ref@1.3.5~preinstall: ref@1.3.5
172 silly preinstall ref-struct@1.1.0
173 info lifecycle ref-struct@1.1.0~preinstall: ref-struct@1.1.0
174 silly preinstall commander@2.11.0
175 info lifecycle commander@2.11.0~preinstall: commander@2.11.0
176 silly preinstall ogg-packet@1.0.0
177 info lifecycle ogg-packet@1.0.0~preinstall: ogg-packet@1.0.0
178 silly preinstall node-opus@0.2.7
179 info lifecycle node-opus@0.2.7~preinstall: node-opus@0.2.7
180 silly doSerial build 72
181 silly build bindings@1.2.1
182 info linkStuff bindings@1.2.1
183 silly linkStuff bindings@1.2.1 has C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules as its parent node_modules
184 silly linkStuff bindings@1.2.1 is part of a global install
185 silly linkStuff bindings@1.2.1 is installed into a global node_modules
186 verbose linkBins bindings@1.2.1
187 verbose linkMans bindings@1.2.1
188 silly build ms@2.0.0
189 info linkStuff ms@2.0.0
190 silly linkStuff ms@2.0.0 has C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules as its parent node_modules
191 silly linkStuff ms@2.0.0 is part of a global install
192 silly linkStuff ms@2.0.0 is installed into a global node_modules
193 verbose linkBins ms@2.0.0
194 verbose linkMans ms@2.0.0
195 silly build debug@2.6.9
196 info linkStuff debug@2.6.9
197 silly linkStuff debug@2.6.9 has C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules as its parent node_modules
198 silly linkStuff debug@2.6.9 is part of a global install
199 silly linkStuff debug@2.6.9 is installed into a global node_modules
200 verbose linkBins debug@2.6.9
201 verbose linkMans debug@2.6.9
202 silly build nan@2.7.0
203 info linkStuff nan@2.7.0
204 silly linkStuff nan@2.7.0 has C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules as its parent node_modules
205 silly linkStuff nan@2.7.0 is part of a global install
206 silly linkStuff nan@2.7.0 is installed into a global node_modules
207 verbose linkBins nan@2.7.0
208 verbose linkMans nan@2.7.0
209 silly build ref@1.3.5
210 info linkStuff ref@1.3.5
211 silly linkStuff ref@1.3.5 has C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules as its parent node_modules
212 silly linkStuff ref@1.3.5 is part of a global install
213 silly linkStuff ref@1.3.5 is installed into a global node_modules
214 verbose linkBins ref@1.3.5
215 verbose linkMans ref@1.3.5
216 silly build ref-struct@1.1.0
217 info linkStuff ref-struct@1.1.0
218 silly linkStuff ref-struct@1.1.0 has C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules as its parent node_modules
219 silly linkStuff ref-struct@1.1.0 is part of a global install
220 silly linkStuff ref-struct@1.1.0 is installed into a global node_modules
221 verbose linkBins ref-struct@1.1.0
222 verbose linkMans ref-struct@1.1.0
223 silly build commander@2.11.0
224 info linkStuff commander@2.11.0
225 silly linkStuff commander@2.11.0 has C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules as its parent node_modules
226 silly linkStuff commander@2.11.0 is part of a global install
227 silly linkStuff commander@2.11.0 is installed into a global node_modules
228 verbose linkBins commander@2.11.0
229 verbose linkMans commander@2.11.0
230 silly build ogg-packet@1.0.0
231 info linkStuff ogg-packet@1.0.0
232 silly linkStuff ogg-packet@1.0.0 has C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules as its parent node_modules
233 silly linkStuff ogg-packet@1.0.0 is part of a global install
234 silly linkStuff ogg-packet@1.0.0 is installed into a global node_modules
235 verbose linkBins ogg-packet@1.0.0
236 verbose linkMans ogg-packet@1.0.0
237 silly build node-opus@0.2.7
238 info linkStuff node-opus@0.2.7
239 silly linkStuff node-opus@0.2.7 has C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules as its parent node_modules
240 silly linkStuff node-opus@0.2.7 is part of a global install
241 silly linkStuff node-opus@0.2.7 is installed into a global node_modules
242 silly linkStuff node-opus@0.2.7 is installed into the top-level global node_modules
243 verbose linkBins node-opus@0.2.7
244 verbose linkMans node-opus@0.2.7
245 silly doSerial global-link 72
246 silly doParallel update-linked 72
247 silly doSerial install 72
248 silly install bindings@1.2.1
249 info lifecycle bindings@1.2.1~install: bindings@1.2.1
250 silly install ms@2.0.0
251 info lifecycle ms@2.0.0~install: ms@2.0.0
252 silly install debug@2.6.9
253 info lifecycle debug@2.6.9~install: debug@2.6.9
254 silly install nan@2.7.0
255 info lifecycle nan@2.7.0~install: nan@2.7.0
256 silly install ref@1.3.5
257 info lifecycle ref@1.3.5~install: ref@1.3.5
258 verbose lifecycle ref@1.3.5~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
259 verbose lifecycle ref@1.3.5~install: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ref\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\FFmpeg\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\FFmpeg\bin;C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm
260 verbose lifecycle ref@1.3.5~install: CWD: C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ref
261 silly lifecycle ref@1.3.5~install: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node-gyp rebuild' ]
262 silly lifecycle ref@1.3.5~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
263 info lifecycle ref@1.3.5~install: Failed to exec install script
264 silly install commander@2.11.0
265 info lifecycle commander@2.11.0~install: commander@2.11.0
266 silly install node-opus@0.2.7
267 info lifecycle node-opus@0.2.7~install: node-opus@0.2.7
268 verbose lifecycle node-opus@0.2.7~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
269 verbose lifecycle node-opus@0.2.7~install: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\FFmpeg\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\FFmpeg\bin;C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm
270 verbose lifecycle node-opus@0.2.7~install: CWD: C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-opus
271 silly lifecycle node-opus@0.2.7~install: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node-gyp rebuild' ]
272 silly lifecycle node-opus@0.2.7~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
273 info lifecycle node-opus@0.2.7~install: Failed to exec install script
274 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-5371d44cf1cca0da.lock for C:\Users\Seyronjunior\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging
275 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ref@1.3.5 (node_modules\node-opus\node_modules\ref):
276 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ref@1.3.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
276 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
277 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
277 verbose optional Failed at the ref@1.3.5 install script.
277 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
278 verbose stack Error: node-opus@0.2.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
278 verbose stack Exit status 1
278 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:289:16)
278 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
278 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
278 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
278 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
278 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
278 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
278 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
279 verbose pkgid node-opus@0.2.7
280 verbose cwd C:\Users\Seyronjunior\Desktop\IronBank
281 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
282 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-opus" "-g"
283 verbose node v8.6.0
284 verbose npm  v5.3.0
285 error code ELIFECYCLE
286 error errno 1
287 error node-opus@0.2.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
287 error Exit status 1
288 error Failed at the node-opus@0.2.7 install script.
288 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
289 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer te faltan dependencias para compilar en Windows, puedes intentar corriendo:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Asegurate de correrlo en una terminal con privilegios de Administrador como está propuesto en la [documentación de node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows)